# MIP for resources to task assignments

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, scheduling

I have few tasks `t1, t2, t3, t4, t5` which need to be assigned to resources `r1, r2`, the tasks are located across multiple districts `d1, d2`, for example `t1, t2, t3` are located in district `d1` and `t4, t5` are located in district `d2`. Each task have some duration like `t1 : 3 hours, t2 : 3 hours, t3 : 4 hours, t4 : 4 hours, t5 : 5 hours` also each resource have `8 hours` of daily capacity.

Here my question is how shall I create decision variables and constraints considering following requirements

1. How do I enforce  that in a day resource can only be in one district ?
   In other words, if resource is in `district d1` then he can only attend `t1, t2, t3`
2. task `t3` can only be assigned to `resource r1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by defining the appropriate binary variable: $x_{ij}=1$ if and only if task $i$ is assigned to resource $j$.

- A given task can only be assigned to one resource:
  $$
  \sum_j x_{ij}=1 \quad \forall i
  $$
- Daily capacity for each resource:
  $$
  \sum_i \Delta_i x_{ij}\le 8 \quad \forall j
  $$
  ($\Delta_i$ denotes the duration of task $i$)
- task $t_3$ must be assigned to resource $r_1$:
  $$
  x_{t_3,r_1}=1
  $$

Can you take it from here ? I will leave you with question 1., which you should be able to do if you understand the above.